# Can I use PHP's preg_replace on UTF-8 data is the matching text is ascii?

Tags: php, multibyte

I have a UTF-8 string like this:

```
$string = "<html> some chars in any language so could be double-byte </html>";
```

I want to lose the `<html>`  and `</html>`

Is this ok:

```
$string = preg_replace("/<html>/", "", $string); 
$result = preg_replace("/<\/html>/", "", $string);
```

i'm not asking for advice re. the regexp (I haven't tested and am sure it could be done better). The question is - if the part I am matching is just ascii (and not multibyte) do I need to use the multibyte regexp functions or is preg sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `preg` is fine with utf - just add the `u` modifier. And yes, as long as your input is ascii it's ok to omit `u`. Due to how utf8 works, if you only deal with asciis, you cannot break other non-ascii chars.

And, of course, you shall not use regexes to manipulate HTML!